# MongoDB $group will not allow me to $project extra fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I almost got this one working, but I simply cannot figure out why the $project part does not work for normal fields....

This is "invoice" table:

```
{
    "_id" : "AS6D0",
    "invoiceNumber" : 23,
    "bookingId" : "AS6D0",
    "createDate" : 1490369414,
    "dueDate" : 1490369414,
    "invoiceLines" : [ 
        {
            "lineText" : "Rent Price",
            "amountPcs" : "8 x 7500",
            "amountTotal" : 60000
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Discount(TIKO10)",
            "amountPcs" : "10%",
            "amountTotal" : -10000
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Final cleaning",
            "amountPcs" : "1 x 5000",
            "amountTotal" : 5000
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Reservation fee paid already",
            "amountPcs" : "1 x -20000",
            "amountTotal" : -20000
        }
    ],
    "managerId" : "4M4KE"
}
```

And this is my query

```
db.getCollection('invoice').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            bookingId: "AS6D0"
        }
    },

    {
        $unwind: "$invoiceLines"        
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            sum: {$sum: "$invoiceLines.amountTotal"}
        }
    },

    {
        $project:{
            "_id" : 0,
            "invoiceNumber" : 1,
            "dueDate" : 1,
            "sum" : 1
        }
    }

])
```

I get the _id and the sum, but it wont show invoiceNumber and dueDate

Comment: Of course, when you group you can't acess any field that is not part of the group. What would you expect to be returned in them ? It's a grouping.

Comment: @MateoBarahona you are correct - but in this case im grouping an array inside the record.  the dueDate and invoiceNumber is not part of that array.  I understand if I grouped a set of records, but in this case its just an array inside. Any ideas?

Comment: As I said, I think you can't expect to get anything that is not defined in the $group clause when you aggregate.

Comment: @MateoBarahona hmmm... it wont allow me to group on other than the _id field (very strange).   Wonder if it would be possible to make $lookup to the same table inside the aggregate and let that one fetch the fields?

Comment: @MateoBarahona ok I get what you mean now, cause the $unwind just turns the internal array into X number of records.   Is there a way to move the `invoiceLines` array into another array, inside the aggregate?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you could use a trick like this : db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            
        }
    },

    {
        $unwind: "$invoiceLines"        
    },
    

    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            sum: {$sum: "$invoiceLines.amountTotal"},
            invoiceNumber: { $addToSet: "$invoiceNumber" },
            dueDate: { $addToSet: "$dueDate" }
        }
    }

]);

Comment: @MateoBarahona you are a friggin genious!!  I did it using a new $lookup to the same table, but your solution is so much more elegant and does not require any extra $lookups.  and it WORKED!! - very smooth, thanks for teaching me something new :)   Please post your reply so I can give you credit.

Comment: Ok ! Glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a trick like this :

```
db.getCollection('invoice').aggregate([ 
{ $match: { } },
{ $unwind: "$invoiceLines" },
{ $group: { _id: "$_id",
sum: {$sum: "$invoiceLines.amountTotal"}, 
invoiceNumber: { $addToSet: "$invoiceNumber" }, 
dueDate: { $addToSet: "$dueDate" } } } 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mateo, this is what I ended up with: 
(I do the unwind on the fields to avoid single value arrays)

Update : You don't have to `$addToSet` to reduce the fields into single value arrays and `$unwind`. Use `$first` instead.

```
db.getCollection('invoice').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            bookingId: "AS6D0"
        }
    },

    {
        $unwind: "$invoiceLines"        
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            sum: {$sum: "$invoiceLines.amountTotal"},
            invoiceNumber: { $first: "$invoiceNumber" }, 
            dueDate: { $first: "$dueDate" }         
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id" : 0,
            "invoiceNumber" : 1,
            "dueDate" : 1,
            "sum" : 1
        }
    }

])
```

Comment: @Veeram - thats great!! I didnt know about $first.  Thanks a lot Veeram :)